# WooCommerce Variable Product Price - Where is "From" text generated from?

Tags: filters, plugins

The following code from [github](https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/1600117) will add "- [max price]" to all variable products displayed in product archives.

I am wondering how I could also remove the "From" text inside the same filter.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);

function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {

     $price = '';

     if ( !$product->min_variation_price || $product->min_variation_price !== $product->max_variation_price ) $price .= '<span class="from">' . _x('From', 'min_price', 'woocommerce') . ' </span>';

     $price .= woocommerce_price($product->get_price());

     if ( $product->max_variation_price && $product->max_variation_price !== $product->min_variation_price ) {
          $price .= '<span class="to"> ' . _x('-', 'max_price', 'woocommerce') . ' </span>';

          $price .= woocommerce_price($product->max_variation_price);
     }

     return $price;
}
```

I noticed [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102863/woocommerce-product-page-edit-from-text) answers how to remove the From text using the same filter parameters, but I haven't been able to figure out how this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with commenting out this line:

```
 if ( !$product->min_variation_price || $product->min_variation_price !== $product->max_variation_price ) $price .= '<span class="from">' . _x('From', 'min_price', 'woocommerce') . ' </span>';
```

and this won't be added to the price output.

Comment: Do you know what `!$product->min_variation_price` means?  Also, how the _x() function works?

Comment: It does mean not - `!` - the products - `$product` - minimal variation price - `min_variation_price`; there's really not more to say. Most of the variation stuff is defined and handled by `class-wc-product-variable.php` if you want to take a look at the source. @RaphaelRafatpanah

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out I have done it but without really exactly how everything works.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 2);

function custom_variation_price( $price, $product ) {

     $price = '';

     if ( !$product->min_variation_price || $product->min_variation_price !== $product->max_variation_price ) $price .= '<span class="from">' . _x('From', 'min_price', 'woocommerce') . ' </span>';

     $price .= woocommerce_price($product->get_price());

     if ( $product->max_variation_price && $product->max_variation_price !== $product->min_variation_price ) {
          $price .= '<span class="to"> ' . _x('-', 'max_price', 'woocommerce') . ' </span>';

          $price .= woocommerce_price($product->max_variation_price);
     }

     return $price;
}
```

I just change this line:

```
if ( !$product->min_variation_price || $product->min_variation_price !== $product->max_variation_price ) $price .= '<span class="from">' . _x('From', 'min_price', 'woocommerce') . ' </span>';
```

to:

```
if ( !$product->min_variation_price || $product->min_variation_price !== $product->max_variation_price )
```

Does anyone know exactly how the _x() function works? I did see [their documentation](http://wpseek.com/_x/) but its not really descriptive.

Comment: You don't need the conditional, if you're not doing something if the condition is met. Take a look at [I18n for WordPress Developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers), `_x()` for distinction by context.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to remove "FROM" text from the variable products:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'variation_price_min',9999, 2 );

function variation_price_min( $price, $product ) {
$prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );
$min_price = current( $prices['price'] );
$price = sprintf( __( '%1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $min_price ) );
return $price;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Wooocommerce still shows "From" even if all the variations have the same price AND you've even chosen a default variation.

I was able to remove it with the following.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'remove_from_text', 10, 2);

function remove_from_text($price, $product) {
  if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices(true);
    $min_price = current($prices['price']);
    $max_price = end($prices['price']);
    
    if ($min_price === $max_price) {
      return wc_price($min_price);
    }
  }
  return $price;
}
```

This modified the `get_price_html` method, checks if the product is a variable product and if the minimum and maximum prices are the same. If they are, it returns only the minimum price, effectively removing the "From" text.